# Does ssh use more CPU than terminator?

Tags: ssh, terminator

If I were to run `watch -n3 "sensors"` on `Terminator` vs using ssh, would it be less resource intensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably yes. SSH is Secure Shell and it uses encryption for the data transferred between two ends.

If you run a command locally, it spawns that command for you and you are done.

If you run the same command over ssh, you start the client process (potentially on other computer), server spawns at least two processes which handle the communication with the client, encryption and decryption. Only after that you will get your command ran.

Comment: But the Terminator will be back .... :) sorry couldn't resist ...